# Is 스시녀 a derogatory word?

Tags: slang, internet-slang

I know many male netizens in South Korea call Korean girls 김치녀 in a derogatory context, in websites such as on Ilbe. I also know they call Japanese girls 스시녀 to contrast it.

But is 스시녀 also considered a derogatory word?

Comment: Don't know about that word in particular, but in general, using "xx녀" is frowned upon by many people (especially women), because they are frequently used to spread sexist stereotypes and/or objectify women.

Comment: The words are referring women to food. Obviously, it is totally humiliating and sexist word. The word 스시녀 is to objectify Japanse women and strengthen stereotypes about them. There are false stereotypes such as 'Japanese girls are promiscuous and submissive' in the society.

Comment: @jungyh0218 Is it also true in South Korea? These words are considered sexist in Western world but in neighboring countries (most notably Japan), it is definitely not true. Surely some, but very tiny number of people might find it humilitating, but most people in Japan take it as offensive only when it is used in such a context.

Comment: I am a native Korean and I bet most of people, especially women would feel pretty much humiliated when they hear the word. I've never seen a cultivated man using this word in real world. It is a kind of internet slang and someone who use it in front of others would be considered a rude, sexist, and racist person. Why do you think that the word which is considered totally sexist in Western countries would be accepeted without any problem in Asian countries?

Comment: By the way, learning Korean expressions from Ilbe is like learning English expressions from 4chan.  Either people won't understand what you say, or they *do* understand and think "Why the hell is this guy advertising that he's a user of *those* sites?"

Comment: @jungyh0218 Isn't it that most (Korean) women find it humiliated is because it is usually used in contrast to 김치녀, which is almost always used in a derogatory context? Yes I know it is an Internet slang and that's why I added the tag (and the scope of my question is restricted in the Internet). As to the last question, because these words are usually accepted in Japan if not used in a derogatory context.

Comment: @Blaszard Even if 스시녀 is used to contrast Japanese women to Korean women, it is still sexist and if Japanese women catch that nuance, they would also feel really shameful. You really can't get why? The word connotes dehumanization in itself! Let me give you another example. On the internet, especially in porn sites, the word 'ebony' means sexy black women. But what if a black woman hears someone calls her 'an ebony'? Would she feel good?

Answer (score 2):

I have never heard about 스시녀 in my life. However, it is a quite easy for me to understand the meaning of it. If anyone who uses or speaks those words to you, I recommend you don't consider him or her as a good person. That's way worse than slangs. If you're a learner of any foreign languages, you might want to learn slangs but not those derogatory words.

Answer (score 0):

저도 스시녀를 여기서 처음 들어서 한 번 찾아봤는데요.

스시녀는 일본여자를 뜻하네요. 일본 스시가 유명하거든요.

비속어이나 무례한 의미로 사용되지는 않는 듯 합니다. 김치녀는 안 좋은 의미로만 사용되는데, 스시녀는 그렇지 않습니다. 어떤 분은 스시녀와 결혼해서 너무 행복하다고 하고, 어떤 분은 스시녀랑 술을 먹게 됬는데 너무 이뻐서 행복한 시간을 가졌다라고 하네요. 오히려 일본여자의 성품을 칭찬하는 데 쓰이는 것 같습니다.

공식적인 자리에서는 당연히 비속어니 쓰면 안되지만, 친한 친구들끼리 있는 자리에서는 써도 무방할 것 같네요.

Comment: Agreed - it's defamatory, but even defamatory, within certain "insider" circles, can take on it's own playfulness.  Still, there are playful defamatory words that I choose to completely refrain from.  I'm sure this is one of them.

Comment: I have a feeling that the poor Japanese lady will be aghast if she ever finds out how her husband calls her...